# Spark - connecting to mysql through Zeppelin EMR

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to connect to MySQL instance from AWS EMR - Zeppelin notebook. Loaded the mysql connector to this location - `/usr/lib/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar` . And added this as an artifact in zeppelin interpreter.

Initiating the driver,

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

res77: Class[_] = class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Using Scala code as here,

Trial 1,

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" ->  "jdbc:mysql://our-host.readm.co.nz:3306/testdb?user=testuser&password=****",
  "dbtable" -> "testdb.tablename",
  "driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "partitionColumn" -> "id", "lowerBound" -> "1", "upperBound" -> "41514638", "numPartitions" -> "20"
  )).load()
```

Got this error,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
STACKTRACE:
java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at <init>(<console>:50)
    at <init>(<console>:55)
    at <init>(<console>:57)
    at <init>(<console>:59)
    at <init>(<console>:61)
    at <init>(<console>:63)
    at <init>(<console>:65)
    at <init>(<console>:67)
    at <init>(<console>:69)
    at <init>(<console>:71)
    at <init>(<console>:73)
    at <init>(<console>:75)
    at <init>(<console>:77)
    at <init>(<console>:79)
    at <init>(<console>:81)
    at <init>(<console>:83)
    at <init>(<console>:85)
    at <init>(<console>:87)
    at <init>(<console>:89)
    at <init>(<console>:91)
    at <init>(<console>:93)
    at .<init>(<console>:97)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at .$print(<console>:6)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1000)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:1205)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  ... 58 elided
```

Then trial 2,

```
val partitionColumn = "id"
val dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://our-host.readm.co.nz:3306"

val lowerBound = 1
val upperBound = 41514638

val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", dbUrl)
    .option("databaseName", "testdb")
    .option("dbtable", "tablename")
    .option("user", "username")
    .option("password", "*****")
    .option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("partitionColumn", partitionColumn)
    .option("lowerBound", lowerBound)
    .option("upperBound", upperBound)
    .option("numPartitions", 20)
    .load()
```

Got this error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  ... 58 elided
```

Trial 3,

```
import java.util.Properties

val table = "tablename"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://our-host.readm.co.nz"
val prop = new Properties()
prop.put("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
prop.put("user","username")
prop.put("password","****")
prop.put("databaseName","testdb")

val jdbcDF = spark.read.jdbc(url,
        table,
        prop)
```

Getting this error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:193)
  ... 58 elided
```

Not sure whats wrong here, can any help me? Thanks.

EDIT:- This is what I am getting after trying the answer given by @geo

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
STACKTRACE:
java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at <init>(<console>:40)
    at <init>(<console>:45)
    at <init>(<console>:47)
    at <init>(<console>:49)
    at <init>(<console>:51)
    at <init>(<console>:53)
    at <init>(<console>:55)
    at <init>(<console>:57)
    at <init>(<console>:59)
    at <init>(<console>:61)
    at <init>(<console>:63)
    at <init>(<console>:65)
    at <init>(<console>:67)
    at .<init>(<console>:71)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at .$print(<console>:6)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor340.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1000)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:1205)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:1165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
Last packet sent to the server was 7 ms ago.
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
  ... 50 elided
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Spark 2.2.0 version

Comment: add jar of mysql  using spark-shell --jars jar_location. Try to connect to connect

Comment: I am trying to run this through zeppelin notebook, not through spark submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your cluster setup? firewall rules etc.? Is mysqld running? Anyway it looks more like a connection issue than a problem with the JDBC driver. Therefore I would recommed: try to connect to MySQL from the host that zepplin is running on via bash

Comment: Thanks. I tried to connect from that host to mysql, still same error. Then found out that the EMR cluster is in public subnet, which does not have connection to database subnet. That is the actual issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the JDBC interpreter works without any problems in Zeppelin, this is what worked for me:

```
// DB connection
val options = Map(
    "url"       -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
    "dbtable"   -> "dbtable",
    "user"      -> "user",
    "password"  -> "password"
)

val data = spark
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .options(options)
    .load
```

It goes without saying that there should be a mysql process running at `localhost:3306` (or wherever you are hosting the DB) and that the firewall/iptables allows you in/out access to/from that process.

Comment: Updated the question with what I got after trying your code.